# What is the most common CW audio filter center frequency?

Tags: cw, filter

For older receivers with a fixed (crystal?) audio filter for CW, what is the usual center frequency of the audio bandpass of the filter?  Or cut-off frequency for low-pass CW filters?

For newer receivers (and external audio DSP boxes) with configurable narrow audio filters for CW, what is the usual default or factory configured center frequency for the narrowest audio filter?

Do experienced operators more commonly increase or decrease the narrow CW filter factory frequency setting?

But I’m especially interested in old radios with fixed frequency (crystal or ???) audio CW filters.

Comment: Some of the answers and comments in [your January 2013 question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/how-low-a-sidetone-frequency-will-allow-qrq-cw-to-be-copied) *partially* answer your question about what tone do experienced operators prefer; however, I think preferences vary.

Comment: If you are trying for the narrowest filter, consider CCW. I hope this is not more than you want to know.
•Coherent CW 
http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/7509026.pdf

Comment: Not asking about the width, just the audio filter center frequency.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen default centre frequencies of between 600Hz and 800Hz depending on the manufacturer. These have always been configurable though, sometimes using a knob, and sometimes with a menu setting.

Not everyone's hearing is the same, and so this should always be configurable. But if I were designing such a system, I would use a default of 700Hz, and allow it to be configurable between 200-2000Hz or so.